# Splitting an input currency into a string and an int

Tags: java, string, split, currency

In a program where currency is input in the form £2 or 10p, for example, is there a method to split this into two variables in the form
    currencyType = £
    currencyValue = 2
or 
    currencyType = p
    currencyValue = 10

where currencyType is a string and currencyValue is an int?

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use patten and matcher classes like below. `\d+` matches one or more digits where `\D+` matches one or more non-digit characters.

```
String s1 = "£2";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\D+)|(\\d+)").matcher(s1);
while(m.find())
{
if (m.group(1) != null)
System.out.println("Currency Type: " + m.group(1));
if (m.group(2) != null)
System.out.println("Currency Value: " + m.group(2));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Currency Type: £
Currency Value: 2
```

**OR**

Use this regex, if you want to deal also with the decimal value.

```
Pattern.compile("(\\D+)|(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wO7nF1/2)

Comment: This won't handle trailing currency correctly, look at my regex for a complete solution. In yours it could have value in group 1 and type in group 2 which would be incorrect.

Comment: really? did you try my code? Value must be in group 2 and type must be in group 1.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

An idea for a solution without regular expressions, although I'd prefer one of those:

```
String entry = "€2.73";
StringBuilder currency = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : entry.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c) || c == '.' || c == ',') {
        value.append(c);
    } else {
        currency.append(c);
    }
}
System.out.println("Value = " + value + " Currency = " + currency);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression to get your result: `"(.*?)([\\d,]*)(.*?)"`
This will split the input into three groups:
1) Leading currency token
2) Value token (can contain a ',', in the string version you can replaceAll ',' with '' and then convert to integer)
3) Trailing currency token

By looking at the groups from the regex, you can figure out if the leading or trailing currency is present and then get the value from the second group. You can write the code yourself by looking up usage for java regex.

Answer (score -1):

You can input your value as a string, split it normally with the split function and assign each value to its own string. Then convert the string to an integer.

int currencyValue = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
String currencyType = array[1];

array[] is the array that you split the string into.

```
String input = user_input.nextLine();
char[] array = input.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isLetter(array[i])){
        //use .split based on the output of the if statement
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't help him as currency type can be prefix or suffix. So you cant guarantee that first element will be value and second value will be Type. N one more thing can you please specify how will you split that?

Comment: i would use something like this (I edited my answer)

Comment: I do agree with the other answers that regex are a better way of doing this